# remove specific text AND line break

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wdo4Lw57/) to explain my problem.

As you can see when you type into the `textbox` and press the `button` the `textbox` value is replaced with `""` but what would I need to do in order to replace the text AND remove the line break?

I'm sure it's something simple that I am overlooking... Thanks.

```
$('button').click(function(e) {
            var info = $('#textField').val();
            var textarea = document.getElementById("todoListSave");
            textarea.value = textarea.value.replace(info, "");
});

<button>Click Me</button>
<input type="text" placeholder="Text to remove from textarea..." id="textField">
<textarea id="todoListSave">
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to replace the line break as well, e.g. with

```
var re = new RegExp(info + '\n', 'g');
```

Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wdo4Lw57/3/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/wdo4Lw57/1/

```
textarea.value = textarea.value.replace(info + "\n", "");
```

This should fix your issue.

You need to add the new line character to the end.

Comment: That didn't seem to work for me, the value inside the textarea just changed to a `0`..